# The java class is not found in JDK 5 environment .. not in JDK 6

Tags: class, java

I developed one stand-alone distributable JAR file using NetBeans 6.9 IDE.My application works fine in JDK 1.6 environement. But, in JDK 1.5 I get error "The java class is not found:  .". Please suggest what could have gone wrong.In JDK 5 environment java bin path is present in PATH variable.

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: Well what class is it? Perhaps it is not included in 1.5 JDK as the error suggests.

Answer (score 1):

THe problem is that you use some class, which has been added in java 1.6. If you want to run your code on java 1.5 you can't use this new class. So, you have choice:

1. Restrict your users from using java 1.5
2. Rewrite your code only using JDK 5.

Comment: it works if I use absolute path while invoking the jar in JDK 5 environment.

Comment: Re your point 2.  So long as you have an `rt.jar` for the target version and the appropriate compilation flags, a Java 6 SDK can compile code to be compatible with *any* previous version of the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 class files are not compatible with Java 5.

In your IDE, you need to set the "target" option to "Java 5" to force the compiler to create Java 5 compatible class files (which will also work in Java 6).

**[EDIT]** It's also possible that you used a class which is only available in Java 6. Please edit your question and show us the complete error message.

Comment: Netbeans 6.9 doesn't have support to start with JDK 5

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't **create projects** with Java 5. The VM of the project != VM of netbeans.